# I'm looking for a C programming app for Android

Tags: android, c, programming

I am in need of a C programming app for my Android phone. The app must:

1. Have an interface to input a program.
2. Inbuilt compiler to compile written programs.
3. Capable of execution.

I do not want any other feature. I don't want a learning app. Just a plain C programming compiler and execution.

I have looked for one on Google Play, but the reviews and comments for the apps there aren't convincing me, so I want to ask you guys out for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have CppDroid on my mobile phone.

It compiles C & C++:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=name.antonsmirnov.android.cppdroid

Comment: On this page: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=name.antonsmirnov.android.cppdroid there is a video that shows all of the features as well as several screenshots.